# Loadrunner general scripting tips

Tags: scripting, loadrunner

I need some tips on how to construct good VUGen scripts in Loadrunner.

First, is it recommended to split a recorded Action() block into separate custom named Actions, not having the entire scenario in one action. If yes, why is this a good practice?

What is the benefit of seperating log in logic in the init() part of the script, if any?

Is it necessary to use iterations? What is the benefit?

Comment: Assuming I have recorded the entire business process as one Action(). Can I just split this big Action block into smaller action blocks by cutting out some part of the business process and sourounding it with i.e. ActionTwo() {..} ? Of course having the login operation in the init part of the script.

Comment: Hi, you might get more replies if you also post the questions on the LR forum http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Support-Forum/bd-p/sws-LoadRunner_SF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the software develop reason, split to logical pieces enables you to configure run logic of the script. For example, if you are in a online shop LT, and have a step to add different stuffs to cart. You could split add to cart to a separate step and specify its number of iteration to run in run time setting.

Comment: And by step here I assume you mean a new Action block, right?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on scripting but:

1) I would split it to logical pieces so that each action has a logical workflow to it. This is a good practice in software development in general and it seems like a good practice here too. This will also allow you to reuse the different actions in another script easily (there is an import action button).

2) The idea of init is that it happens only once during load. You can later change the logic of this - for example wait until all the virtual users run their init and only then start the load test.

3) It is diffidently not necessary and I am not sure what are the benefits.

Hope that helps a little.
Please see my comment on the question.